# Review audits, banned again - bad luck?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I really didn't want to complain, but I got banned pretty much instand again because of the review audit system.

Last week I got banned for seven days, for a audit that I really disagree with. I was mad, as I already had an unclear audit just before. Also I was reviewing hundreds of tasks in these days and I got quite a lot of audits right, but it only needed two wrong to ban me for a week, and they where bad audits.
This morning, happy to be able to review again, I jumped into the "Low Quality Posts" section, after two reviews I got [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10579514), and I pressed edit as I could see bad formatting, and would read the post while editing.
But nope, no time for reading I got banned instandly, by just pressing the Edit-Button, not even submitting anything.

I think I understand the review system quite well, but these audits are way to random and way too punishing. Can a moderator review failed audits and unban people?

PS: now that I see that there is a Tag disputed-review-audits, I probably should have posted them earlier.

Comment: You attempted to edit spam...Spam is spam is spam - even if it looks like it has genuine content (to mask what it's trying to spam) the action to take is to get rid of it - not to try and salvage it in some way...

Comment: As I already mentioned, I perfectly acknowledge this is a post that has to be deleted. Again, I pressed Edit to continue reading after the bad formatted section. I feel really bad.

Comment: Also can you have a look at the other audits?

Comment: The audits you failed on the 9th and 4th were posts deleted via vote in the VLQ

Comment: But was I that wrong with my choices? Also consider the amount I was answering correct in the time. I know the audit system just has a look on how much in wrong in 30 days.

Comment: Trying to edit this spam one - definitely. The one on the 9th - umm... not 100% sure it needed to be deleted (there was some information there) but the community didn't want it - so not necessarily wrong on that one. The one on the 4th was essentially a link only answer - so, yes to that one.

Comment: I did **not** edit the spam =( --- Also why would I vote delete on a post that has valid information, if can *see* it has downvotes and maybe some comments, but why should I delete it without even leaving a comment and leaving the chance to improve it? --- The link answer, if I remember correctly, was an OK answer! Why? It was not a classic link answer, it was referencing to a tool, so it had to give a link about that tool, information was given in the answer, so it was ok. It should not have been deleted

Comment: By choosing edit (whether you make an edit or not - just the fact you chose edit)  it indicates to the system you think something positive can be done with the post - while in the case of spam - there's nothing positive that can be done. The "You can use <link to tool here>" is still link-only and if the link becomes invalid, so does the answer. The OP had time to edit in details if they wanted to before it was removed via queue.

Comment: But you are a human, smarter then the System? How should I have known, it would judge me on pressing edit, for me edit is just another view, not an action yet! --- The linkpost had the name of the tool, plus a link. While maybe bad it should be given a chance to be improved. Remember that while in a audit, you can not see anything done on the post. Thats why I would of cause chose to give it a chance and improve it!

Comment: I think this is the curse of the people who really go to review with an incredible amount of motivation. They don't skip enough but rather push through even medium doubts, and thus get eaten alive by the heartless audit monster.

Comment: @gnat the link has nothing to do with that post, but thanks anyway

Comment: ["You attempted to edit spam..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312507/review-audits-banned-again-bad-luck?noredirect=1#comment283638_312507)

Comment: Let's try and keep the tone of your post and comments civil, hey @CodeiSir?

Comment: You must be joking? I was not using any bad words by fare, but I was telling the truth. And you just delete my comment and my Edit?

Comment: 4 People just came in to flag the post as doublicate, and I guess by review queue. Oviously the did not even read the post but voted for close. I have screenshots of this now, you wont delete this one.

Comment: @JonClements and if you have some time, please answer my last comment/message to you 3 hours ago, where I explained my actions..

Comment: @CodeiSir what wasn't clear in what I said? The system is automated - it isn't perfect. But if you choose to click edit on a post that's been removed as spam -you're saying it's salvageable. Read the post as a whole first, then if it looks like it's reasonable to do an edit, then do so. As to the link only answer - the OP had time to improve it - they did not - so the community removed appropriately as link only.

Comment: @JonClements ... I have to repeat my self once again. Or well I'll just copy paste: "While in a audit, you can not see anything done on the post." how could I now that it has not been improved? I had to NOT delete it!!! And I got banned for leaving a chance to somebody to improve his post. It might very well have been the perfect answer to the question anyway! --- About the automated system I appelled to you, as an Human Moderator to handle the problem in this case, would you please undo the ban? Why do you support the flaws of the System?

Comment: lol "OK, I bypassed the alarm system, looped the video surveillance, picked the lock on the back door and placed a ring of cutting charges around the vault door. Since I was arrested before I could do anything further, you should not charge me with attempted bank robbery since you cannot be sure that I was going to rob the bank".

Comment: @MartinJames well accuse me of murder, attempting to press the edit button --- "How should I have known, it would judge me on pressing edit, for me edit is just another view, not an action yet!" - in my question you can read my statement, that I didnt finish reading it, and wanted do so in the edit VIEW

Comment: For those of us who have enough reputation to go through the low quality posts ([2000](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)) but not enough to see deleted posts ([10,000](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) - I think), could you post the (redacted) answer in the question please?

Comment: What does this post have to do with the "duplicate"? This is not my question at all =(

Comment: The review process is basically StackOverflow's troll training program. If you genuinely want to help your fellow coders, the audit process is designed to kick you out.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of a review, *"Edit" is a decision* - just like the others - rather than a way to "better read the question" or whatever.

Moreover, since editing ends the review process, it's even stronger a "Keep" vote than a normal "Keep" vote.

Why is it implemented line this? Let's see:

- When you press the "Edit" button in a normal review, you get an editing view where you can

  - see the raw markup
  - improve the question
- But, when you press the "Save" button,

  - you don't just save your changes like it would be if you edited with the "edit" link in the normal UI, you also cast an "Edit" vote
- So, *it doesn't make sense to click the edit link if you aren't going to cast an edit vote. Unless you just prefer to read the markup rather than the rendered text* for some reason

  - Thus allowing you to edit in a review audit would be a *land mine:* your editing efforts (potentially unlimited) would be unconditionally wasted - by far worse a surprise than *just* failing an audit

    - Basically, booby-trapping the normally "safe" "Edit" button - counterintuitive, yes - is seen as a lesser evil (="the best we could think of").

      - It may also be a way to shove it into your face that making the decision *before* pressing anything is the correct course of action.
      - You are free to make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) if you can think of anything better

Comment: As already mentioned,I did not "edit" the post. Rather confusing, but a different thing: I pressed the "Edit" button to attempt an edit, getting the edit view. But with the intend to finish reading the post in the Edit view. I would certainly not have pressed the save edit button. As of now of cause I understand that in case of an audit that is already too late. And I don't think it is OK to ban someone because of that.Especially together with the other problems of the audit System it is unfair to ban people that review much,and get many audits right.

Comment: But then will sooner or later fail an unclear audit, as the ones I mentioned. It feels very unfair, as I am investing a lot of time and correctness in my reviews.

Comment: I tell you, from the system's point of view, you didn't "open an edit view", you made a decision.

Comment: I know...now. Suggestion to improve: it should at least wait for the user to save the edit.

Comment: Then your editing efforts would be wasted - that's probably the reason.

Comment: It's allowed in other audits. Why would it not be here? I wasted a lot of comments and edits in these audits

Comment: By the way that was not my question. That answer is more than obvious when you see the result of pressing the edit button..

Comment: I already created a bug report regarding comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270236/cannot-edit-a-comment-in-review-ui .

Comment: The rationale regarding comments as I see it is: an audit's purpose is to validate your decision and nothing else. Any irrelevant actions are presumed unhelpful to others because you're being fed inaccurate information.

Comment: That would be OK if you knew it's an audit, but if you dont know it is one, you might very well press that edit button in first place. Don't you think so?

Comment: @CodeiSir See the update(s).